# std::list containing std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdlist

What I'm trying to achieve is `std::list` that contains `std::functions`. I'm trying to implement a callback system where functions can be added to the list and then the list can be looped through and each function called.

What I have in class A is:

```
std::list<std::function<void( bool )>> m_callbacks_forward;

bool registerForward( std::function<void(bool)> f ) { m_callbacks_forward.push_back ( f ); return true; };

void GameControllerHub::invokeForward( bool state ) {

    for( std::list<std::function<void(bool)>>::iterator f = m_callbacks_forward.begin(); f != m_callbacks_forward.end(); ++f ){

        f();
    }

}
```

And then in class B

```
std::function<void(bool)> f_move_forward = [=](bool state) {
        this->moveForward(state);
    };

    getGameController()->registerForward ( f_move_forward );
```

...

```
bool Player::moveForward( bool state ) {
...
}
```

But in `GameControllerHub::invokeForward` I get error

> "type 'std::list >::iterator' (aka '__list_iterator') does not provide a call operator"

I'm compiling with Xcode

Answer (score 4):

You need to dereference the iterator to get the element it referes to. The iterator itself doesn't have `operator()`.

Write `(*f)(state);` or, if you wish, `f->operator()(state);`

Comment: Ok... Now I get no matching function for call to object of type 'value_type' (aka 'std::__1::function<void (bool)>')  when I try to use (*f)();  but with ->operator()(state) it compiles thou crashes at runtime =/

Comment: @EinoT I overlooked that you have a parameter. Fixed that. As to why you get a crash, that I can't tell.

Comment: The crash happens on std class list: `template <class _Tp, class _Alloc>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
void
list<_Tp, _Alloc>::__link_nodes(__node& __p, __node& __f, __node& __l)
{
    __p.__prev_->__next_ = &__f;
    __f.__prev_ = __p.__prev_;
    __p.__prev_ = &__l;
    __l.__next_ = &__p;
}`

EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: Oh. More precicely it happens when I try to push to to list: `bool registerForward( std::function<void(bool)> f ) {
  m_callbacks_forward.push_back ( f );
  return true;
 };`

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the function element from the iterator before calling with `*`. Think of it like a sort of "pointer" to the desired value (the `std::function` object), you have to "dereference" it:

```
for( std::list<std::function<void(bool)>>::iterator f = m_callbacks_forward.begin(); f != m_callbacks_forward.end(); ++f ){
    (*f)();
}
```

By the way, if you can use C++11, then take advantage of the for-each loop:

```
for (std::function<void(bool)> f: m_callbacks_forward) {
    f();
}
```

or even more concise with `auto`:

```
for (auto f: m_callbacks_forward) {
    f();
}
```